# Sort Column header based on row value, and show as columns

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

We have sheet with column names and values in the cells below.
We like to have a list of the names and the value next to it ordered.

example.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Mary | Tom | Grace |  |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |  |

and we would like the same data below which looks like...

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 5 |
| 2 | Mary | 4 |
| 3 | John | 3 |
| 4 | Grace | 2 |

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D2), 2, )
```

[image]

or:

```
=SORT(TRANSPOSE({A1:D1; A4:D4}), 2, )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. This is works great for me. I didn't know you could transpose using code. 

Answer (score 2):

### SUGGESTION

Perhaps you can try this way:

> `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:D2),"SELECT * order by Col2 DESC")`

### Sample Sheet

> [image]

### Reference

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thanks, what if the the values were on e.g. row 4 (other data in between which i'm not interested in) ?

Comment: @DevilDog Can you share a sample on that to better visualize it? You may update your original question & include data that you're actually working on.